# QGIS Export from QGIS2WEB takes 1.5 minutes with labels turned on and 4 secs with labels turned off

Tags: qgis, export, web-mapping, qgis2web

In a project, I have a layer containing 7000 features, 7 meg big which are polygons, lakes.  500 features have names.  I am only trying to create a map with this one layer.  If I create a web map in QGIS2WEB, with labels turned off, the Update Preview takes 4 seconds to display the layer and on EXPORT, it takes 5 seconds to display the map in Firefox.

If I turn on single labels, with value of NAME, with no other settings changed, the Update Preview takes 1.5 minutes to display.  If I EXPORT the map it takes 5 seconds for the Progress dialog box to complete showing the export and writing of the layer to JSON, writing HTML etc.  It then takes 1.5 minutes for the map to be rendered in the Firefox browser and when imported into Wordpress, takes the same time to be rendered.

I have not made any other changes to the layer such as symbology, etc.

The resulting map with labels on is 16 meg.

I have exported the layer in QGIS to a copy and have the same problem.  I have displayed the map in Chrome and MS Edge and it takes the same 1.5 minutes to be rendered.  I have deleted all but two columns from the attribute table for the layer with no change.  Any suggestions to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide .qgz project and files without sensitive data?

Comment: Do you want just the layer in question or do you want all layers in the project?

Comment: How do I provide the requested files?

Comment: upload a zip to any web location or use dropbox, google drive etc..

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Here is link to the zip: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6VtnAlBV26kghl3jYQOjLN4mCV?e=fTad4M

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data provided, I understand that you are using a Leaflet export, which does not manage label declutter or minzoom and maxzoom.
Perform an Openlayers export, you will find the choice below in the qgis2web plugin. You will see that the map will be fast because the labels will only appear at a certain zoom.
Greetings.